# I want to find a relation between $X(l,t)$ and $Y(l,t)$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X(l,t)=4t \sum_{n=0}^{l-1} \binom{2n}{n}t^n \ $ and $ \ Y(l,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{l-1}n \binom{2n}{n}t^n$, where $l \in \mathbb{N}$.

I want find an explicit relation between $X(l,t)$ and $Y(l,t)$.

**My approach:**

Multiplying $Y(l,t)$ by $4t$, we get
$$ 4tY(l,t)=4t \sum_{n=0}^{l-1} n\binom{2n}{n}t^n.$$

But still it is not equal to $X(l,t)$ because of the absence of the factor $n$ in $X(l,t)$.

I could not find a relation between $X(l,t)$ and $Y(l,t)$.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Hint: Take the derivation of $\frac{X(l,t)}{4t}$ with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}Y(l,t)&=&t\sum_{n=0}^{l-1}n\binom{2n}{n}t^{n-1}\\&=&t\cfrac{d\left(\sum_{n=0}^{l-1}\binom{2n}{n}t^n\right)}{dt}\\&=&t\cfrac{d\left(\frac{X(l,t)}{4t}\right)}{dt}\\&=&\cfrac{1}{4}t\cfrac{d\left(\frac{X(l,t)}{t}\right)}{dt}\\&=&\cfrac{1}{4}t\cfrac{\cfrac{dX(l,t)}{dt}\cdot t-X(l,t)}{t^2}\\&=&\cfrac{1}{4}\left[\cfrac{dX(l,t)}{dt}-\cfrac{X(l,t)}{t}\right]\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{X}{4t} \right)= \sum_{n=0}^{l-1} n \binom{2n}{n} t^{n-1} =\frac{Y}{4t^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}